# Trying to install fann2 python library, error: "failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, pip, installation, fann

I am new to python and I keep getting errors when I am trying to install new packages.

This time I tried to install the Fast Artificial Neural Network Library, fann2.

I am trying to install from the command prompt, running the following line from the python 3.6 path: `python -m pip install fann2`

Here is my Log:

```
*  Failed building wheel for fann2


*Command "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-q8ncpiq8\\fann2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-v7aj23q_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-q8ncpiq8\fann2\
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when trying to install [Mycroft AI](https://mycroft.ai).

It looks like the python installer requires you to already have the FANN libraries installed somewhere on your system path.

You can get the fann files from their [download page here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/download/), but I just got mine from the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fann/) so I'm probably not much help for your environment.

Answer (score -3):

[instruction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGybbtYiSEk&index=3&list=PL8fA_qjSFodf_RiWz-7441XQu8Cm0F25z)

setup.py file has an exception

some python libraries require various complex manipulations before installation, for example, pre-building a library in C++. To avoid this, some libraries have already been collected and can be found on the [website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

after downloading it remains to run the command
pip install file_name